# Between query within a database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2016

I've been trying to solve this problem for ages and still have no luck.

I am trying to set up a vehicle database in where I check the availability of vehicles on dates in which I enter for people can rent them out. For example, they want to rent a vehicle from November 05/11/2016 till 20/11/2016.

I have been able to connect the query back to the vehicle table but when i test the query it either gives me all the vehicles being listed as available or none of them.

I have included the tables and the relationships as I think the table between each one may be causing me the problem.

Any suggestion to fix this code is much appreciated.

[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D54Zb.png) 
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy9em.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE Vehicles.vehicle_id NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT distinct Booking.[vehicle id]
        FROM Booking
     WHERE (
    [Enter Start Date] BETWEEN booking.start_rent_date
        AND booking.end_rent_date
    )
OR (
    [Enter End Date] BETWEEN booking.start_rent_date
        AND booking.end_rent_date
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as a `left join`:

```
select v.*
from vehicles v left join
     bookings b
     on v.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id and
        b.start_rent_date <= @EnterEndDate and
        b.end_rent_date >= @EnterStartDate
where b.vehicle_id is null;
```

A vehicle is not free if there is a rental that starts before the desired end date and that ends after the desired start date.  The `left join` excludes these.  You could also use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` for equivalent logic.

EDIT:

Oh, you are using MS Access . . .

```
select v.*
from vehicles as v left join
     (select b.*
      from bookings as b
      where b.start_rent_date <= @EnterEndDate and
            b.end_rent_date >= @EnterStartDate
     ) as b
     on v.vehicle_id = b.vehicle_id
where b.vehicle_id is null;
```

Comment: i am getting a syntax error for a missing operator any idea why they might be happening

Comment: It was working for me at the start but now when i try it all the vehicles are showing up any idea how that is happening

Comment: nevermind was entering the dates the wrong way man... Thank you so much i was a couple of hours trying to solve this i owe you so much thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Vehicles
WHERE   Vehicles.vehicle_id NOT IN (
                                    SELECT distinct D1.[vehicle id]
                                    FROM Booking D1
                                    WHERE ( DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.start_rent_date, @Enter_Start_Date)>=0
                                            And DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.end_rent_date, @Enter_Start_Date)<=0
                                            )
                                            OR 
                                            (
                                            DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.start_rent_date, @Enter_End_Date)>=0
                                            And DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.end_rent_date, @Enter_End_Date)<=0
                                            )
                                            OR 
                                            (
                                            DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.start_rent_date, @Enter_Start_Date)<=0
                                            And DATEDIFF(DAY, D1.end_rent_date, @Enter_End_Date)>=0
                                            )
                                    );
```